# Issue Windows / Excel - Seeing a hidden opended excel file in Python although all instances closed

Tags: excel, python-3.x, windows-10

I have this issue where an Excel file appears to be opened when I use Python although there is no Excel instance running. It is impossible to see it via Windows, even with the hidden files option selected ; only using Python in this case (the last item in the list on the last line of code) :

[image]

Moreover, it persits even when I tried the following :

- Deleting the file,
- Copy/paste the whole folder somewhere else,
- Renaming the file,
- Rebooting...

This is a nightmare... I can't figure why windows would keep a hidden file openened somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

@Boris

Is there someone who has opened/editing this file on a remote/remote desktop connection?

Comment: no, that's the thing... nobody is on this file... and it has been deleted. This is not the first time I have this issue with users. They appear to be using a file when they are not.

Comment: This is not an answer, and it should be a comment; kindly delete